# Calculate rolling standard deviation from the 20th row onwards

Tags: r

I have a data frame of various columns. I need to calculate the standard deviation of a particular column `Spread`. The standard deviation should appear in another column.

The standard deviation should be calculated from the 20th row onwards till the last row of the data frame. This implies that the standard deviation on the 20st row should be the standard deviation of the first 20 values. On the 21st row the standard deviation should be of the data from row 2 to 21 and so on.

While there are many posts on the calculation of standard deviation, I could not find the one relevant for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

Use `rollapply` function of `zoo` package

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(data = dat$Spread,width=20,FUN=sd)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a go with this function:

```
rollingSD <- function(x, h = 5) {
  if (is.numeric(x) && length(x) >= h && h > 0) {
    c(numeric(h-1), sapply(1:(length(x)-h+1), function(i) sd(x[i:(i+h-1)])))
    }
  }
```

It applies rolling standard deviation on a input vector `x`, and the window size is `h`. In your case, you should pass `h = 20`.

**Experiment**

```
set.seed(0); r <- rnorm(10)
# [1]  1.262954285 -0.326233361  1.329799263  1.272429321  0.414641434
# [6] -1.539950042 -0.928567035 -0.294720447 -0.005767173  2.404653389
rollingSD(r, h = 5)
# [1] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.7305264 1.2012939 1.2973930
# [8] 1.1045270 0.7719939 1.5063519
```

If your data frame is called `dat`, then this is what you can do:

```
dat$sd <- rollingSD(dat$Spread, h = 20)
```

This applies `rollingSD` to column `Spread` with window size 20, and save the result to a new column `sd`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `roll_sd` from `RcppRoll` (data from @ZheyuanLi's post)

```
library(RcppRoll)
roll_sd(r, 5, fill=0, align = "right")
#[1] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.7305264 1.2012939 1.2973930
#[8] 1.1045270 0.7719939 1.5063519
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified toy example using a for loop. Assume column `a` in `df` holds your data. Let's calculate the standard deviation for the first 3 values, then value 2 to 4, etcetera. You can modify it for your purpose. You can then add the sd's to a new column in your data frame `df`.

```
a <- c(10,100,1000,10000,100000)
df <- as.data.frame(a)

b <- c(NA, NA)
for (i in 3:NROW(df)){
  b <- c(b, sd(c(df$a[ c((i-2):i)] )))}
df$b <- b

df
#      a          b
#1 1e+01         NA
#2 1e+02         NA
#3 1e+03   547.4486
#4 1e+04  5474.4863
#5 1e+05 54744.8628
```

Notice that in the first step we add two `NAs` to `b`; because the sd for the first three values goes in row 3 in `df`.

Alternatively, set window size `w` and use in `for loop`. Now you don't have to modify the entire script each time you change the window size.

```
w = 3
b <- c(rep(NA, w-1))
for (i in w:NROW(df)){
  b <- c(b, sd(c(df$a[ c((i-(w-1)):i)] )))}
df$b <- b
```

You can also make a function.

```
roll_sd <- function(string, window){
b <- c(rep(NA, window-1))
for (i in window:NROW(df)){
  b <- c(b, sd(c(df$a[ c((i-(window-1)):i)] )))}
return(b)}
```

Try the function using the toy example.

```
roll_sd(df$a, 3)
#[1]         NA         NA   547.4486  5474.4863 54744.8628
```